# Upgrade to 4.7.29 causes Internal Server Error with cron

Tags: cron, scheduled-job

I upgraded our test site to 4.7.29 (type fixed) yesterday and the cron has been failing since then with a 500 server error.

We are running on Wordpress 4.9.2. The cron has been working successfully until now for years.

We have a cron job running every 30 minutes using the URL to cron.php method.
I've checked the cron.php permissions; they haven't changed and have checked that the user and password are still valid and have enough permission (they do). When I run the command directly from the command line I also get a 500 internal server error, same with running it in a browser. The only thing we did was upgrade the version of CiviCRM.
Help?

Comment: Try upgrading it to 4.7.29 .

Comment: Can you paste the error log please.

Comment: Sorry - that was a typo. It is version 4.7.29

Answer (score 1):

So I resolved the issue. Here's what I found. It looks like the permissions for **bin** have changed from **755** to **775** at some point (I looked at one of our backups and it used to be 755, but in 4.7.29 it was set to 775.)

I used this question and response:
[URL for cron Jobs gives me a 404 error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19989/url-for-cron-jobs-gives-me-a-404-error/20004) (not the same error, but I was desperately searching!)

Made the same changes (**updated bin permissions to 755**) and it all worked. So that's good (for now) but with every upgrade will we have to remember to update permissions?